# Flask to read and write to same csv

Tags: python, flask, export-to-csv

I have a flask app that was created using a csv file.  Using html forms, I give the user the option to input new data, and then I write changes to the csv (using a custom function) and download it. This downloads just fine and saves to my desktop.  Is there any way to tweak the code to save it in the same project directory and overwrite the csv that serves the flask app? This way the app might update upon refresh. Thanks!

```
@app.route('/csv/')
def download_csv():

    model_id=request.args['textid']
    client_id = session['client_id']


    # return response
    df=recommender.update_history(client_id, model_id)
    df= recommender.get_csv()
    resp = make_response(df.to_csv(encoding='iso-8859-1',index=False))
    resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
    return resp
```

Comment: Did you try to give `df.to_csv()` a filename?

Answer (score 0):

The comment above is correct. I didn't need the make_response function.  Here's what worked:

```
@app.route('/csv/')
def download_csv():

    model_id=request.args['textid']
    client_id = session['client_id']


    # return response
    df=recommender.update_history(client_id, model_id)
    df= recommender.get_csv()
    path=r'data/file_name.csv'
    resp = df.to_csv(path, encoding='iso-8859-1',index=False)

    return render_template('index.html')
```